# How to redirect a domain to WordPress subdirectory on GoDaddy with cPanel?

Tags: redirection, wordpress

I am using WordPress to create a website for an author friend. The website is `www.essex-history.com` with wordpress installed at `www.essex-history.com/wordpress`

If I set up 301 redirection of the (GoDaddy) domain to the `/wordpress` directory (using cPanel), the wordpress pages fail to open with a 'too many re-directs'.

In WordPress, in Settings/General, the entry in both the WordPress Address and Site Address fields points to `www.essex-history.com/wordpress`.  (However, changing the Site Address entry to reflect `/wordpress` or not doesn't seem to make any difference at all.)

Some time ago I managed to make `www.utting.org` point successfully to `www.utting.org/site` (the WordPress folder), but I can't replicate what I did!

All I need to do is to get `www.essex-history.com` to point to `www.essex-history.com/wordpress`!

Answer (score 1):

First: As others have said - turn off your GoDaddy redirect. Get the settings for your website/hosting back to how you originally received them because they just work!

Why didn't you read the WordPress Codex pages???? They have the answer to exactly what you want.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Method_II_.28With_URL_change.29

> **Moving process**
>
> (p.s. If you've already installed WP in subdirectory, some steps might
>   be already done automatically).
>
> 1. Create the new location for the core WordPress files to be stored (we will use /wordpress in our examples). (On linux, use mkdir
>      wordpress from your www directory. You'll probably want to use chown
>      apache:apache on the wordpress directory you created.)
> 2. Go to the General Screen.
> 3. In **WordPress address (URL):** set the address of your main WordPress core files. Example: http://example.com/wordpress
> 4. In **Site address (URL):** set root directory's URL. Example: http://example.com
> 5. Click Save Changes. (Do not worry about the errors that happen now! Continue reading)
> 6. Now move your WordPress core files (from root directory) to the subdirectory.
> 7. Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog
>      address). The .htaccess file is invisible, so you may have to set your
>      FTP client to show hidden files. If you are not using pretty
>      permalinks, then you may not have a .htaccess file. ***If you are
>      running WordPress on a Windows (IIS) server*** and are using pretty
>      permalinks, you'll have a web.config rather than a .htaccess file in
>      your WordPress directory. For the index.php file the instructions
>      remain the same, copy (don't move) the index.php file to your root
>      directory. The web.config file, must be treated differently than the
>      .htaccess file so you must MOVE (DON'T COPY) the web.config file to
>      your root directory.
> 8. Open your root directory's index.php file in a text editor
> 9. Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says: `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );` to the
>      following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:
>      `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`
> 10. Login to the new location. It might now be http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
> 11. If you have set up Permalinks, go to the Permalinks Screen and update your Permalink structure. WordPress will automatically update
>       your .htaccess file if it has the appropriate file permissions. If
>       WordPress can't write to your .htaccess file, it will display the new
>       rewrite rules to you, which you should manually copy into your
>       .htaccess file (in the same directory as the main index.php file.)

Personally, I'd start from scratch by using the GoDaddy cPanel to install WordPress to your custom directory so that you have to get to it by typing the full URL, then follow the steps above. You'll then have a clean install knowing what you want to do will work from the get go.